# Apply border radius property to browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I am working on a project and the client gave me a task to open a browser window on the click of button like a popup but it is not a popup, I have to open a browser window and that is not complicated but they gave me a design to give **border radius to browser window and make browser window's sides *CURVY*** like in the image.

[image]

I did not find any solution of this. Is it possible? If yes then please reply me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: "to give border-radius to the browser window and make browser widow's sides curvy" - This is not possible. The closest thing you can do is to create a modal and style it according to the design.

Comment: You cant apply CSS to browser.

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER: You cannot make a *WINDOW* with curved corners**

You would have to rewrite the browser code to do so.

CSS does not apply to the browser itself, only the content

But you can pop a curved div:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document.getElementById("popBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("popDiv").classList.toggle("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #CEEDDC
}

div.pop {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 55px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="popBtn" type="button">Pop</button>
<div id="popDiv" class="pop hide">
  <h1>Here you could have an iFrame if needed</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I said browser window not any div mean chrome browser with curve sides or firefox browser with curve sides. understand ???

Comment: I can popup a window. It is not difficult but I don't have solution that how can give border-radius property to browser window

Comment: because it is not the answer of my question, and I dont want to create popup. Hope you understand.